# jquery file upload error: has no method 'abort'

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, jqxhr

I'm trying to implement cancel action for **file upload plugin** and have some issue with aborting `jqXHR` request.

```
$('#filedd').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "",
        progress: function (e, data) {},
        add: function(e, data) {           
                req = data.submit();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    req.abort();
                }, 100)           
        }
);
```

And I get result that

> req has not method 'abort'

I've tried other options like `reject()` it's OK, but it doesn't cancel the upload (break request).

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you can abort the upload like that because it does not use XMLHttpRequest to upload the file, it is a normal file upload using an iframe.

Comment: what you mean iframe? this is ajax post reqest. in header it says: X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: which is the plugin used & browser used to test

Comment: In browsers which does not support `FormData` api the file upload is done using a iframe based form submission solution

Comment: I'm testing it on Chrome (last build), jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.26

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? There is a known issue with 1.7

Comment: Yes, I have 1.7... Will check this on higher version.

Comment: Updated to version 1.7.1. All works fine now. Thanks a lot!